# WMI copy folder\file to remote server with no share c#

Tags: c#, wmi

I have been trying to copy folder\file from local to remote server using wmi with c#. of course there are some questions like this on StackOverflow already e.g. "[Remote WMI copy folder](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16245461/remote-wmi-copy-folder)". But in my case there is no shared folder on local\remote. I just have IP,AdminName and password.
Is there any way to achieve this?

Comment: Is the login account on the remote machine an administrator? If yes then you can use the default admin shares `\\computer\c$` etc (and you can use an IP address rather than the computer name).

Comment: yes account is an administrator account. I can connect to remote server successfully, even able to get all the files,folders etc. The problem is how to copy some file\folder from local to remote. can you please provide some sample code?

Comment: I don't have code to hand... but I would [create a share](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/4215/How-to-create-a-file-share-using-NET-framework) and then use [`File.Copy`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.file.copy) recursively.

Comment: Isn't there any way to use "CopyEx" method of WMI ?

Comment: WMI can be used to do this, it just seems to me to be a hard way of doing it (despite the additional step of creating a temporary share). With WMI if you execute the WMI method locally you still need the destination share; if you run it remotely you need to get a `Win32_Directory` instance for the source machine on the destination machine... which may still require a destination share (the `CopyEx` actually executing on the source machine).